# best way to intersect multi sets haskell

Tags: haskell, tuples, intersection

```
type MSet a = [(a , Int)]
```

what is the best way to do the intersection of multi sets in haskell language? ty

```
intersect :: Eq a => MSet a -> MSet a -> MSet a
```

example:

```
[('a',3),('b',5),('c',1)] [('d',5),('b',2)]
>[('b',2)]
```

Comment: See https://hackage.haskell.org/package/multiset-0.3.2/docs/Data-MultiSet.html#v:intersection

Comment: That `Eq a` constraints greatly limits your efficient solutions. If you could go with `Ord a`, then you could consider one of the [`intersection`](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=intersection) functions.

Answer (score 2):

Look at something like this:

```
> [(n,min x y)|(n,x) <- [('a',3),('b',5),('c',1)], (m,y) <- [('d',5),('b',2)], n==m]
[('b',2)]
```